# Crypting data with a X509 certificate in PHP

Tags: php, ssl, x509certificate

I need to send crypted data to a payment site and their instructions tells me this:

> -X509 public certificate : "This site" will generate a X509 public certificate
>   for every merchant account created. You’ll have to use this certificate in order
>   to encrypt data every time you initiate to "this site" a
>    payment. This cannot be
>   used to decrypt data, "this site" will use a private key to decrypt.

From what I know and what I saw in PHP documentations, you can only check with certificate if data is signed. So how could I encrypt data with this certificate given and do what they want?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between signing and encrypting? Because in the title you ask about signing but in the question about encrypting. Signing is to prove that you are the sender of the message, encrypting is to protect the data against sniffing and manipulation during transport. Signing with a certificate needs the private key of the sender, encrypting with a certificate needs the (public) certificate of the recipient.

Comment: As on how to implement your specific problem there is more context needed how they exactly expect the encryption to be done. Please provide more of the documentation or link to it.

Comment: While the question no longer confuses signing and encryption after the edit it still does not provide the needed information to determine how the payment site is exactly requesting the encryption. Please add the necessary documentation or provide a link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are searching for the function [`openssl_public_encrypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php). For this to work you have to load the openSSL extension for PHP, which is quite likely enabled, but maybe not.

For an example how to get the key, see comment [in the same doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#104420) (basically using [`openssl_pkey_get_public()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php))
But instead of using `fopen()` and `fread()` you could also use `file_get_contents()`, which would be my preferred way.